# How can I get only status code without parsing the body?

Tags: http, go, httprequest, httpresponse, http-response-codes

Title is say.
I need only status code. Not response body.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://api.example.com/getUserList", nil)
    res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req) // <-- 300KB Full page downloading here
    fmt.Print("status code", res.StatusCode)
}
```

How can i interrupt response stream after got status code?
(or its possible?)

Thanks

Comment: Thats what HEAD is for.

Comment: @Volker I have a feeling OP is working with a RESTful webservice that uses `POST` to create a resource and returns status code 201 upon success, so in that context I can imagine why he would want to ignore the response body.

Comment: @Volker but I need to do POST request on the server like that. I cant use HEAD or other methods.

Comment: @ErkanErdem The response body is not "downloaded" until you explicitly read from res.Body, so simply closing the stream is all you need to do.

Comment: Are you sure you need `POST` method? Purpose of this method is to *send data* to server or *perform* some action

Comment: @EmilePels i checked in mitmproxy. body is downloading here.

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky api owner is not me. i just write like web scrapper

Comment: Try to use custom http client and set very little buffer to it. Then close body

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky  but I need some help with how I can do it

Comment: @ErkanErdem: what exactly do you need help with? You either read the body, or you don't. It's up to you, but in a full program you always need to close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is... it's probably not possible.

Generally speaking, an HTTP client will *always* retrieve the full response (status, headers, *and* body) for any response that includes a body since that is just how HTTP works. Note that the "HEAD" method specifically does what you want but since you must use the "POST" method it obviously doesn't apply here.

As commenters have mentioned, in some sense you can simply ignore the response body by not reading it (as your current example does) but the client system will still incur the network cost of downloading the body - it just won't surface in your application.

It's theoretically possible that you could implement a custom HTTP client (or perhaps configure an existing client) so that it attempts to terminate the underlying TCP connection as soon as the HTTP status is retrieved and ignores the remainder of the HTTP response; however, this strategy is likely very complicated and would be subject to a large number of factors that might be out of control of the application.

Ultimately, your example code is probably the best you can do to pay attention only to the status code and ignore the response body. It might be worth closing the response reader immediately to indicate to the HTTP library that the associated resources are not needed and can be freed immediately; however, there's no guarantee that it would have any effect. Moreover, you might be able to configure the HTTP client to use a very small buffer for the response body in an attempt to minimize the resources used before closing the body, but again, probably no guarantee that this would actually prevent the response body from being sent over the network.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second paragraph. The Client won't download the full body unless you actually read it (minus what's pulled into the relatively small buffer). If you close the body without reading it, the transport will close and discard the connection, eventually resulting an an RST if the server continues to send.